# Slash in parameter Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django as a restful api, and i have urls like                        `url(r'^datavore/(?P<configuration>.*)/(?P<dataset>.*)/(?P<varname>.*)/(?P<region>[a-z-A-Z\_]+)/(?P<date_range>.*)/filelist/$', views.filelist,name="filelist"),`

my problem is when the dataset parameter contains '/' it modify the structur of my url the dataset parameter contains only the string after the / . Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Replacing slash with its encoded value (`%2F`) on the calling side might work, but I'm not sure if the URL matching is done before or after the URL is decoded.  The best answer is probably to avoid using URL parameters that can contain literal slashes.  You could also change this from GET to POST.

Comment: I tested the %2F but it dosen't work, i can't really change the / because that's how its indexed, i think maybe i should encode the parameter in base64 format on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one parameter can have slash then your problem can be solved by specifying regex where only one capturing group is allowed to have slash. For example:

```regex
^datavore/(?P<configuration>[\w\d\.\-_]+)/(?P<dataset>.*)/(?P<varname>[\w\d\.\-_]+)/(?P<region>[a-z-A-Z\_]+)/(?P<date_range>[\w\d\.\-_]+)/filelist/$
```

`datavore/some-config/dataset/subdataset/varname/region/date-range/filelist/` will result in next values for matching groups:

```
datavore/some-config/dataset/subdataset/varname/region/date-range/filelist/
144 steps to match

configuration   [9-20]  `some-config`
dataset [21-39] `dataset/subdataset`
varname [40-47] `varname`
region  [48-54] `region`
date_range  [55-65] `date-range`
```

If several groups can have slash in them then there is no accurate way to properly match them withou using extra text in path. Example solution with extra text in path:

```regex
^datavore/__conf__/(?P<configuration>.*)/__dataset__/(?P<dataset>.*)/__varname__/(?P<varname>.*)/__region__/(?P<region>[a-z-A-Z\_]+)/__date_range__/(?P<date_range>.*)/filelist/$
```

```plaintext
670 steps to match
datavore/__conf__/conf/subconf/__dataset__/dataset/subdataset/__varname__/varname/subvarname/__region__/region/__date_range__/date-range/filelist/

configuration   [18-30] `conf/subconf`
dataset [43-61] `dataset/subdataset`
varname [74-92] `varname/subvarname`
region  [104-110]   `region`
date_range  [126-136]   `date-range`
```

Note that `/__dataset__/` is use instead of simple `dataset` you may want to user have value for dataset wich starts with `dataset` itself. This will cause problems:

```plaintext
^datavore/conf/(?P<configuration>.*)/dataset/(?P<dataset>.*)/varname/(?P<varname>.*)/region/(?P<region>[a-z-A-Z\_]+)/date_range/(?P<date_range>.*)/filelist/$
```

```plaintext
datavore/conf/conf-val/dataset/dataset/dataset-val/varname/varname-val/subvarname-val/region/region-val/date_range/date-range-val/filelist/

654 steps to match

configuration   [14-30] `conf-val/dataset` // THIS SEEMS TO BE WRONG. We wanted this to be `conf-val`
dataset [39-50] `dataset-val` // THIS SEEMS TO BE WRONG. We wanted this to be `dataset/dataset-val`
varname [59-85] `varname-val/subvarname-val`
region  [93-103]    `region-val`
date_range  [115-129]   `date-range-val`
```

Actual solution highly depends on possible values for your capturing groups

If you are using this path as API endpoint then I'd recommend to just dump  this approach and use GET parameters instead

Comment: using regex where capturing groups are disallowed to have slash is about 3.5 times faster (41 steps instead of 144) than regex where slashes are allowed in single capturing group. Using regex where all groups are allowed to have slash is about 16 times slower than using groups without slashes (670 steps to match). No regex will be used if you switch to GET query parameters.

Comment: "No regex will be used" is wrong: url still should be matched. But it will be much faster to match simple expression like `^datavore/filelist/$`

Comment: Thank you, i only have one slash in the dataset parameter so your first solution works perfect for me .

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a different separator character between parameters than inside parameters. After parameters have been matched, you can always replace that separator by the slash that should actually be there inside the parameters.

So, either those parameters that use a slash internally allow for some other safe character like a dash or a dot (meaning that there is a character that cannot occur otherwise due to the nature of the respective parameter), or you have to decide on some separator character and create some escaping rule.